# How to convert date to yyyy-mm-dd format using ssjs without timestamp

Tags: marketing-cloud, datetime, date, ssjs, conversion

I am trying to convert the date to YYYY-MM-DD format using SSJS. But not able to do that. Getting NAN.

```js
var day = new Date();
var prevDate = new Date();
yesDate.setDate(day.getDate()-1);
var test = (yesDate);
```

test gives me the yesterdays result but in different format. `"Wed, 03 Jun 2020 09:28:53 GMT-06:00"`. How can i convert that to YYYY-MM-DD format without timestamp?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

You should be able to use the following function to format it correctly:

```js
function formatDate(date) {
    var d = new Date(date),
        month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
        day = '' + d.getDate(),
        year = d.getFullYear();

    if (month.length < 2) 
        month = '0' + month;
    if (day.length < 2) 
        day = '0' + day;

    var formattedDate = year + '-' + month + '-' + day;
    return formattedDate
}
```

You will notice that for month, I use a `+ 1` to it, this is because Month is a 0 indexed value. Meaning Januaray is 0 and December is 11. So by adding 1 you push it to the correct numeric representation of that month.

You would just call it like this:

```js
var day = new Date();
var prevDate = new Date();
prevDate.setDate(day.getDate()-1);
var test = formatDate(prevDate);
```

When you then output `test` it should come out as `2020-06-03`. (assuming today is 2020-06-04)

Comment: Thanks @Gortonington. But I am getting 2020-05-03 as output.As getMonth() is zero indexed I have added getMonth()+1.Which gave me the expected output. Will there be any effect when the month reaches to 11,12?

Comment: @Harry Good catch! I completely forgot about it.  There will be 0 effect on it in later months. It goes from 0-11, so adding 1 will always push it to the correct month.  I am going to update my answer now.

Comment: Okay. Thanks @Gortonington.